# Passing Object in es6 Template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I have this below code segment

```
${res.result.map(resultObj =>
`<div class="col-sm-4 mb-4">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getEditable(resultObj)">Edit</a>
 </div>`
)};


window.getEditable = (resultObj) => {
  console.log(resultObj);
}
```

This throws error "results" is not defined.
How should I pass the results object to a function using Template String ?

Also would like to ask is using window. is a good approach ?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Does it throw that error only when you click on the button?

Comment: What is that `${…};`?

Comment: You should not use a template string for HTML. Use the DOM, and attach your function as an event listener. No, using a global `window.getEditable` variable is not a good approach

Comment: @OliverRadini Yes it throws error when button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you're looking to be able to have html reflect the state of an object which may change, and that normally means being able to watch that state in some way. This often means using a library/framework, like React, or Vue, as doing this kind of reactivity is not easy once a project gets beyond a trivial size.

---

Here's a minimal example to demonstrate the problem:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('output')

const values = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
]

const log = text => {
  console.log(text)
}

el.innerHTML = values.map(valueIter => `
  <button onclick="log(valueIter)">
    ${valueIter.id}
  </button>
`);
```

```html
<button onclick="log(valueIter)">Test Button</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In the above example, the *text* `valueIter` gets put into the `onclick` function call, the the actual object which is part of the `map` call. Replacing this with `${valueIter.id}` would instead pass the text of the `valueIter`'s id property. If this changes, though, we would still get the original value.

An alternative would be to access the actual value which is to be logged:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('output')

const values = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
]

const log = text => console.log(text)

el.innerHTML = values.map((value, i) => `
  <button onclick="log(values[${i}])">
    ${value.id}
  </button>
`)

values[0] = {
  id: 99
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

You'll notice that the text of the button doesn't change. There's nothing in this code to force the DOM to update once the original value changes, which is where things get quite a bit more complex. There's essentially nothing binding the output of the DOM to the state of the object it is supposed to be rendering.

Comment: That is an amazing explanation..Thank you so much

Comment: You're most welcome, let me know if anything's unclear, it may well be down to my explanation!

Comment: It is pretty much clear to me...but the issue is when I click on the button, it says "values" is not defined

Comment: the `values` part needs to refer to whichever part you're looking to use, for you I think it'll be `results`, for instance. It needs to be available to the function that's being called, of course.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, because of an excellent explanation and approach. Though I couldnot get this to work :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use id

```
res.result.map(results =>
  `<div class="col-sm-4 mb-4">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getEditable(${results.id})">Edit</a>
  </div>`
);

var getEditable = id => {
  var resultObj = res.result.find(elem => {
    return elem.id == id;
  });
  console.log(resultObj);
}
```

> Also would like to ask is using window. is a good approach ?

Using window object in this case is a bad practice

Comment: I tested this code on jsbin and it's works correctly